# Iterating through children of Listview

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList filled with Integers and a Listview. Now i wanna got through this Arraylist, and if `status.get(i) % 2 != 0`, i wanna strike through the according child of a ListView filled with TextViews.

**My code:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < mLsitView.getCount(); i++){
            TextView tv = (TextView) mLsitView.getChildAt(i);
            if(mArrayList.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
            tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); 
           }
        }
```

When i perform this code, its giving me a NullPointerException, telling me: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TextView.getPaintFlags()' on a null object reference`.

I've already searched the internet, but i couldn't find a solution. Somebody said you should use `for (int 1 = 0; i < mLsitView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - mLsitView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++` in the loop, but it just returns 0 for me and the piece of code doesnt get performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViews are different from regular Views in that the children of a ListView don't all exist at once. ListViews generate just enough child Views to fit on the screen of the device, plus a few extra. As you scroll through the ListView, the children Views that disappear off the top of the screen are [recycled and placed at the bottom again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCVVm.jpg) for reuse so that the phone doesn't have to constantly be creating and destroying Views.

To put a strike-through on every other View, you have to create a custom [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). When your Adapter is called, it also receives the position of the View you're creating and you can use that to determine whether or not to paint the strike-through.

Comment: Ty for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do like that because list will not create all the view in one shot,

You can solve this problem by put you condition in `getView` in your adapter.

Comment: I dont understand your point. Could you explain it so a beginner can understand it?

Comment: Go to your list adapter(should be custom list adapter), check you will have getView() method, In that, you will get the TextView anyway, you can modify based on the position in that.